# Moveit Group not found: issues executing a plan via cpp

Tags: ros, rviz, moveit, movegroup, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have created a standard MoveIt! package. I want to control this package "sia5d_cmd" using a node.  There are lots of examples of code for this, but no explicit information as to how to get a custom made node to talk with a MoveIt! package.

I have my MoveIt! package (sia5d_cmd) and the package that contains the node (test_moveit) I want to run in the same catkin workspace. I demo.launch the MoveIt! package which contains a group called "sia5d".  I then launch my node test_moveit_node.cpp as normal.  This is my code for that:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <moveit/move_group_interface/move_group.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "MoveGroupInterface"); //ros::init_options::AnonymousName
  // start a ROS spinning thread
  ros::AsyncSpinner spinner(1);
  spinner.start();
  // this connects to a running instance of the move_group node
  move_group_interface::MoveGroup group("sia5d");
  // specify that our target will be a random one
  group.setRandomTarget();
  // plan the motion and then move the group to the sampled target
  group.move();
  ros::waitForShutdown();
}
```

This is the error I get:

```
[FATAL] [1530796096.618661297]: Group 'sia5d' was not found.
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  Group 'sia5d' was not found.
```

I am sure there is some issue with how I am connecting these things together.  I am a bit newer to ROS than most, but information online about this is surprisingly sparse and poorly documented and I have been trying for a week to be able to plan/move the robot in RViz using a node.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/296397/moveit-group-not-found:-issues-executing-a-plan-via-cpp/) by [Levi_Manring](https://answers.ros.org/users/36261/levi_manring/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2018-07-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-07-05**:\

> I am a bit newer to ROS than most, but information online about this is surprisingly sparse and poorly documented

The [MoveIt tutorials](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/) are pretty extensive and would seem to cover this ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> [FATAL] [1530796096.618661297]: Group 'sia5d' was not found.
> ```

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  Group 'sia5d' was not found.
```

your SRDF does not contain a group definition called `sia5d`. That is why you get the error.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1